# how to create filter records

Tags: json, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

i want to create filter record for my database realtime database firebase in my android program
but I don't understand how to use it and place it, can you guys help me in dealing with this case

[image]

Comment: What are the exact filter are you looking for?

Comment: I want to make a filter like where in sql for my android application, using a realtime database, is that possible? @AlexMamo

Comment: For sure there is. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks for adding it. Now, what is the exact filed you want to filter on?

Comment: I want to filter the name and policy number section @AlexMamo

Comment: So you need to combine filter? Is that right?

Comment: thats right sir @AlexMamo

Comment: In that case, please check the duplicate.

Comment: where is duplicate ? @AlexMamo

Comment: At the top of the page.

Comment: in firebase sir ?@AlexMamo

Comment: In this page at the top